# Getting Euler angle from VRPose.orientation Quarternion

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, webvr

I need to get the angle **theta** between the direction the phone is facing and the horizon (see pic).

[image]

For it, I'm using the web-vr polyfill library, which allows me to access VRPose.orientation, the orientation of the camera as a quaternion.

Now, I'm trying to convert the quaternion to a Euler angle, so to be able to get the **theta** angle I need, but with my attempts that angle is not independent to the other rotation angles (ie. if the user turns around from its position, while keeping the phone in the same orientation, the angle **theta** changes).

This is my code.

```
  var orientation = frameData.pose.orientation
  var a = orientation[0]
  var b = orientation[1]
  var c = orientation[2]
  var d = orientation[3]

  var yaw, pitch, roll

  roll = Math.atan(2*(a*b + c*d)/(pow2(a) - pow2(b) - pow2(c) + pow2(d)))

  pitch = - Math.asin(2*(b*d - a*c))

  theta = Math.atan(2*(a*d + b*c)/(pow2(a) + pow2(b) - pow2(c) - pow2(d)))
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong or suggestion of another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the quaternion onto a unit vector and then calculate the angle:

```js
const vec = new THREE.Vector3();

function getCameraAngle() {
  // Reset the vector to a unit vector pointing into the scene
  vec.set(0, 0, -1);
  // Apply the camera quaternion
  vec.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
  // Calculate the angle based on Y
  return Math.asin(vec.y) * THREE.Math.RAD2DEG;
}

const angle = document.getElementById('angle');

function animate() {
  angle.textContent = getCameraAngle().toFixed(2);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};


// Boilerplate
new WebVRPolyfill();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.vr.enabled = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
WEBVR.createButton(renderer);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight('white', 1));

let grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
scene.add(grid);
grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
grid.position.set(0, 5, -5);
scene.add(grid);
grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
grid.position.set(0, 5, 5);
scene.add(grid);
grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
grid.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
grid.position.set(5, 5, 0);
scene.add(grid);
grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
grid.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
grid.position.set(-5, 5, 0);
scene.add(grid);
grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.position.set(0, 10, 0);
scene.add(grid);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#angle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/webvr-polyfill@0.10.6/build/webvr-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.95.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.95.0/examples/js/vr/WebVR.js"></script>

<span id="angle"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very very much!